# API Error Code: 191 Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

I'm having a problem connecting my website with a Facebook page.

The error is:

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

My app configuration settings are:

- App domain: mercatdocasio.hol.es
- URL: http://mercatdocasio.hol.es/

The configuration of page code is:

```
fbconfig['baseurl']    = "http://mercatdocasio.hol.es/index.php"
```

Where is the problem?

In my localhost works but in my website doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

When you request a permission dialog, you provide a redirect_url with it. This URL should be in your application scope.

Try to set on Facebook Developers Application settings screen domain of your application to `mercatdocasio.hol.es`.

If it will not work, then your redirect_url in permission dialog is invalid (specifies other domain).